# How to automate VPN connection on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, automation, windows-10

I'm going to be traveling for the next month, and I'd like to automate the VPN connection process so that on X event, the script fires and automatically connects me.  I've already configured the [L2TP/IPSec] VPN connection in `ms-settings:network-vpn` & verified it works, but it's automation step that's proving problematic.

Windows GUI: The credentials have been saved.

`PowerShell`: The `RememberCredential` property is set to True

`VBScript`: Curiously, the VPN connection is hidden:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim NetConn : Set NetConn = oShell.Namespace(49)
Dim Connections : Set Connections = NetConn.Items
wscript.echo "Connection Count [" & Connections.Count & "]"
For i = 0 to Connections.Count - 1
    wscript.echo "Connections.Item(" & i & ").Name: [" & Connections.Item(i).Name & "]"
next
```

`rasdial <entry>`: Expectedly returns error 691.

`rasphone -d <entry>`: Displays the Connection dialog whereas I'd prefer it to just connect automatically and hidden.

Is this even possible in Windows 10?  Or am I just overlooking some small yet key detail?

Comment: Why is it hidden?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine.  I have 9 objects in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections (`::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}`): yet in VBScript, it returns everything except the VPN connection.

Comment: Is it SSTP connection?

Comment: It's not SSTP, its L2TP/IPSec.  I'm wondering if the same rules apply.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up leveraging `Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication` to trigger an automatic connection of the VPN on the launch of specific executables/UWP applications.  The downside is that when doing this, PoSh warns that SplitTunneling must be enabled which is less than ideal.

However after playing around with it for a while (just 2 or so hours now) to ensure the VPN keys off specific executables/UWP's, I ended up disabling SplitTunneling and, paradoxically, it *appears* to continue working as I would hope/expect.  I rebooted a few times, logged on and sure enough by the time the desktop loaded the VPN had been established.

I need to do more testing to confirm, but this is sufficient to help save me from myself.

Comment: It's seems like it's also possible to 'split' the tunnel like this, which in practice sends all your traffic over it: `Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "My VPN" -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/1"` and `Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "My VPN" -DestinationPrefix "128.0.0.0/1"`

Comment: Good data point.  Back then I wasn't interested in this but today there might be a valid use case for that.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by checking the `Remember my sign-in info` checkbox when I created the VPN connection.

You can check this in your PowerShell script by ensuring that `Get-VpnConnection` returns `RememberCredential    : True`.

If this is the case, then rasdial should automatically connect it.

I do it with this:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Ensures vpn connection (assumed to have saved credentials) is connected.
#>
function Connect-Vpn
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [object]
        $Settings
    )

    $rr1 = Get-VpnConnection -Verbose:$false | where {$_.ServerAddress -imatch $Settings.VpnConnectionPattern -and $_.RememberCredential} | Select -First 1
    if ($rr1.ConnectionStatus -ne 'Connected')
    {
        rasdial.exe $rr1.Name
        If (-not $LASTEXITCODE)
        {
            throw "Cannot connect to '$($rr1.Name)'."
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Verbose "Already connected to '$($rr1.Name)'."
    }
}
```

You will have to massage this code to your needs as this uses some fields from my settings file...

Comment: It looks like it could have worked if `rasdial` did not return `Expectedly returns error 691`, as OP specifies.

Comment: This link is the best I can do to guess at the cause for the 691. http://superuser.com/questions/486741/connect-to-vpn-using-command-line-results-in-error-691 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/163111/remote-access-service-ras-error-code-list.